# reduce width of columns on a heatmap.2 plot

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I have a 331*9 double matrix (named expr001). It looks like this:

```
row.names     Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4      Col5      Col6    Col7       Col8      Col9
17211382  7.397439  7.377975  7.299997  8.192889  8.292300  8.092921  8.178948  8.120986  8.276824
17211752  9.115307  9.116741  9.113366  8.423073  8.458392  8.573309  8.773752  8.614159  8.592105
17212229  5.968911  6.060437  6.059898  5.595364  5.471327  5.538794  5.584753  5.518935  5.498830
17215629  8.641765  8.810358  8.770533  7.482992  7.732727  7.811839  8.582255  8.404402  8.357516
17215820 11.495858 11.605611 11.529879 11.124909 11.107311 11.179045 11.165894 11.188668 11.210991
```

And I am generating a heatmap using heatmap.2

```
heatmap.2(expr001,main="\n331 Genes : P.adj<0.01",cexCol=0.9,tracecol=NULL,col="bluered")
```

I get the plot below:

[image]

How can I reduce the width of the columns? Any suggestions?

Comment: Make the font smaller and/or the plot larger. You have only so many pixels to work with. If they don't fit then they don't fit.

Comment: How can I make the plot larger?

Comment: I tried using the png("image.png", width = 800, height = 600) function before my heatmap.2() function but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pheatmap` package. There you can control the size of the the cells more conveniently, with arguments `cellwidth` and `cellheight`. Even if your plot becomes too big this way and does not fit into the plotting window, then by using argument `filename` you can write it into file with correct measurements.