# How to adjust the width of heatmap columns plotted using seaborn

Tags: heatmap, seaborn, column-width

I am plotting a heatmap using seaborn and I spent the last day or so trying to adjust the width of the columns because currently they are very wide. From my own search I was to find ways to adjust the size of the heatmap, or the line separating the columns but not the columns themselves. Is this doable using seaborn or should I use another tool?

This is a simple command that I am using:

`sns.heatmap(mydata, cmap='Reds')`

Answer (score 0):

So after spending more time on this I realized that I could do this easily using pheatmap. You will need to use "cellwidth" parameter to control the width. So for example, `pheatmap(mydata, cellwidth = 100)`. This question was asked for pheatmap here [link] [reduce width of columns on a heatmap.2 plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859692/reduce-width-of-columns-on-a-heatmap-2-plot?rq=1) before, but I initially wanted to use seaborn to generate the heatmap. I am still interested to know whether seaborn has a way to control the width.